# Tick Python instances from Python

Tags: python

I am interrested in doing a programming game using python, and I would like to do it in the style of GunTactyx (http://apocalyx.sourceforge.net/guntactyx/index.php). Only much simpler, as I am primarily interrested in the parallel execution of python scripts from python.

Gun Tactyx challenges the player to write a program that controls individual units working together in teams, where each instruction carries a time panalty. Each program is executed in its own protected environment, communicating with the game world through functions that can interact with the game world.

I was wondering if there is a Python way of achieving similar effect.

Pseudo code structure of the game engine would be something like:

```
Instantiate units with individual programs
while 1
   Update game world
   for unit in units:
      unit.tick()
```

The simulation would run until a timeout or some goal condition.

Kind regards

/Tax

Comment: What you are looking for is interprocess communcation in Python? E.g. program 1 talks to program 2 and so forth?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into fork of python: [stackless](http://stackless.com), it allows concurrently running thousands of micro-threads without much performance penalty - every "thread" (these aren't real OS threads) could be one Unit.

Also it's very easy to implement Actor model with stackless:

> In the actor model, everything is an actor (duh!). Actors are objects (in the generic sense, not necessarily the OO sense) that can:
>   Receive messages from other actors.
>   Process the received messages as they see fit.
>   Send messages to other actors.
>   Create new Actors.
>
> Actors do not have any direct access to other actors. All communication is accomplished via message passing. This provides a rich model to simulate real-world objects that are loosely-coupled and have limited knowledge of each others internals.
>
> from [`Introduction to concurrent programming with stackless`](http://members.verizon.net/olsongt/stackless/why_stackless.html#actors)

Alternatively, you could also simulate this behavior by implementing co-routines - using python generators, like shown [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/). But I'll guess you'll be better off with stackless, as it's all there already.